# error in sql syntax for python and mysql on insert operation

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-2.7

I am trying to execute following similar type 2 sql queries. While one query is executing successfully but other is giving error

```
db = MySQLdb.Connection(host="192.168.1.90", port=3306, user="some", passwd="some", db="some")
cur = db.cursor()
cur.executemany("""INSERT INTO test (timepacket,model_no,cycle_time,target,plan,count,difference,bekido,linenumber,shift,runningstatus,remarks) VALUE (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""", datater)
db.commit()
cur1 = db.cursor()
cur1.executemany("""INSERT INTO delay (running,change,nomaterial,breakdown,quality,noplan,line,shift) VALUE(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""", datater1)
db.commit()
db.close()
```

The first query is working ok while second query is giving error

> 1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'change,nomaterial,breakdown,quality,noplan,line,shift) VALUE(507,0,0,0,0,0,1,1)' at line 1")
>   Anyone can help me out why it is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`change` is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html). If you named a column "change" you will need to wrap it in ticks.

(I'm not a python dev so I am guessing this is correct):

```
cur1.executemany("""INSERT INTO delay (running,`change`,nomaterial,breakdown,quality,noplan,line,shift) VALUE(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""", datater1)
```